# How to find the equation of a plane in the form $ax + by + cz = d$ which contains two lines, $l$ and $m$?

Tags: vectors

The equations of the lines are given:

$l:$ $$r = i + j + k + s(i - j + 2l)$$

$m:$ $$r = 4i + 6j + k + t(2i + 2j + k)$$

We are also told that the lines intersect, and the angle between the two is $74.2°$. That's all the information we have been given.

This is my working:

$$(1,-1,2).(a,b,c) = 0$$ because the dot product would be zero considering the normal of the plane would be perpendicular to the direction vector of both lines.

$$a-b+2c=0$$

$$(2,2,1).(a,b,c)=0$$ using the same principal, but for the line $m$.

$$2a-2b+c$$

The mark scheme says something about solving the ratios and then obtaining the answer, but I did not understand. This is A Level Mathematics P3.

The answer of this problem is $5x-3y-4z=-2$.

I tried finding the cross-product of the two lines, but I'm getting the wrong answer. Even if I do find the cross product, I don't know how to find $d$.

So how would I solve this and what am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly $\;i,j,k\;$ is just another name for the coordinate axis, so your lines are

$$\begin{align*}&\ell_1: (1,1,1)+s(1,-1,2)=(s+1,\,-s+1,\,2s+1)\;,\;\;s\in\Bbb R\\{}\\&\ell_2: (4,6,1)+t(2,2,1)=(2t+4,\,2t+6,\,t+1)\;,\;\;t\in\Bbb R\end{align*}$$

Comparing both rightmost expressions, we find the intersection point:

$$\begin{cases}t+1=2s+1\implies t=2s\\2t+6=-s+1\implies s=-2t-5\\2t+4=s+1\implies s=2t+3\end{cases}$$

Lines $\;2-3\;$ give us $\;4t=-8\iff t=-2\;$, and then line $\,1\,$ gives $\;s=-1\;$

so the intersection point is $\;(0,2,-1)\;$, which can be then take as the "anchor" point together with both direction vectors of the lines, and the plane is

$$\pi: (0,2,-1)+s(1,-1,2)+t(2,2,1)$$

For the other form find first the (a) normal to the plane by the vectorial product:

$$(1,-1,2)\times(2,2,1) =\begin{vmatrix}i&j&k\\1&\!\!-1&2\\2&2&1\end{vmatrix}=(-5,3,4)$$

So the plane is $\;-5x+3y+4z+d=0\;$. Inputting $\;(0,2,-1)\;$ gives us $\;d=-2\;$ and thus $\;-5x+3y+4z-2=0\;$ is the plane

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't understand why we expressed the vector as pi. Why was that necessary?

Comment: That is not a vector but a more or less usual way to denote a plane, just as using $\;\ell\;$ is a usual notation to express a line. At least in vectorial form.

Answer (score 1):

You have two equations in three variables. There are infinitely many solutions, and any one would give you a normal vector. After all, there are infinitely many normal vectors to a plane.

After you get a normal vector, just take an arbitrary point that you know is on the plane and use it to find the remaining constant in the equation for the plane.

Comment: So if I were to find the dot product of the two directional vectors and equate them both to zero, how would I proceed? I have two equations for a, b and c. What next?

Comment: @KrunalRindani: Solving them to get the general solution is basic linear algebra. In this case, use one to substitute the other and you'll get one equation in two variables. You can then see that you have multiple solutions. Just pick one by fixing one of the two remaining variables at say $0$, and then you will get one solution for the three variables. That would give a normal vector.